# How to capture a webview to bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, webview, capture

I have a webview, and I need to scroll down to view all the content. Now, I want to **capture the entire of the webview** to a bitmap.

I looked for many times. People suggested me use the function `capturePicture()`. However, this function is **deprecated**. So, what other methods I can use to do to reach my goal?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution. Take a look of this.

I used the onDraw to replace the capturePicture functon which is deprecated in API 19. If you have any better solutions, please tell me and I appreciate that. Thanks!

[Which can replace capturePicture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942623/which-can-replace-capturepicture-function/20963109#20963109)

Answer (score 14):

Android L, you need to call WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() before creating any WebViews. That is, if you have any WebViews in your layout, make sure you call this method before calling setContentView() in your onCreate().
linked [Mikhail Naganov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4477684/mikhail-naganov):https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084485/703225

```
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
    }
    ...
    setContentView(layout);
    ...
    ...
}
```

then:

```
/**
 * WevView screenshot
 * 
 * @param webView
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap screenshot(WebView webView, float scale11) {
    try {
        float scale = webView.getScale();
        int height = (int) (webView.getContentHeight() * scale + 0.5);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        webView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

if you don't use webView.getScale(), also:

```
public static Bitmap screenshot2(WebView webView) {
    webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight());
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, iHeight, paint);
    webView.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur help. when I debug, 'webView.draw(canvas);' this line takes 3 seconds. Is there no way to use this line?? When I remove this line, I got a blank page.

Comment: sorry, I hava no idea. :-( The page is too large?

Comment: I'm using this answer successfully, without having to call enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw, on my Pixel 3a with Android 11.. thanks!!