# android webview full page screen capture

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to capture webview full page content as a screenshot(bitmap) in android but no luck. Tested many solutions suggested in stackoverflow and other sites. Please help.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), webView.getContentHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
webView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
```

Comment: Is there any error or what happen actually ..... post some code.. what did you try ..

Comment: capturePicture method is deprecated in API level 19, other linked http://stackoverflow.com/a/35959284/703225

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    WebView w ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    w = new WebView(this);
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                    Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
                    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

                    picture.draw( c );
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {

                        fos = new FileOutputStream( "mnt/sdcard/yahoo.jpg" );
                            if ( fos != null )
                            {
                                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                                fos.close();
                            }
                        }
                   catch( Exception e )
                   {

                   }
          }
      });

    setContentView(w);
    w.loadUrl("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=android");
}
```

I found this from hear.. [click.](http://w3facility.org/question/how-can-i-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-webview-capturing-the-full-page/)
did you try in this way.

Comment: Yes but capturePicture method is deprecated in API level 19 and that method  returns null on api level 19 or higher and as per the documentation "Use onDraw(Canvas) to obtain a bitmap snapshot of the WebView, or saveWebArchive(String) to save the content to a file."

Comment: -it creates image with a full height of the page, but only display contain is captured within screenshot, the bottom of screen shot will remain blank any idea? and Will it work if we load HTML data instead of WebURL ?