# Take snapshot of webview android 5.0+

Tags: android, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, snapshot

I have a code to take snapshot of WebView and it works perfectly on pre-L versions:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float changeSizeCoefficient = calculateChangeCoef(displayMetrics);
    int sizeTo = (int) (238f * displayMetrics.density * changeSizeCoefficient);

    int height = webView.getWidth() > webView.getContentHeight() ? webView.getContentHeight() : webView.getWidth();
    Bitmap snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(snapshot);
    webView.draw(bitmapCanvas);

    Bitmap resizedSnapshot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snapshot, sizeTo, sizeTo, false);

    if (!resizedSnapshot.equals(snapshot))
        snapshot.recycle();

    return resizedSnapshot;
```

But on 5.0+ versions the invisible part of WebView on snapshot is filled with white color.

How can i take snapshot of all WebView on Android 5.0+?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078157/webview-draw-not-properly-working-on-latest-android-system-webview-update/30084485

Comment: @Ufkoku Can you please put your code for calculateChangeCoef so, it can help others as full solution for the question?

Comment: @NovusMobile I asked this question 2+ years ago, and at the moment I can't access this code. I guess you can use an answer above, suggested by Mikhail Naganov, or an answer below, by sahulab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This implementation of taking snapshot of `WebView` will work on any Android device,**

->Put the `WebView` in a `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_web_webview_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
       <WebView
           android:id="@+id/wv_webview_activity"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />
</FrameLayout>
```

-**After that declare and fetch the resource id for both** `FrameLayout` **and** `WebView`

Inside your `Activity` write

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_webview_activity);
FrameLayout  fl_web_webview_activity = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fl_web_webview_activity);
```

After that  put this method in `Activity` Class

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Now call above method to get the Bitmap data of your **`WebView`**

```
Bitmap b = loadBitmapFromView(fl_web_webview_activity, fl_web_webview_activity.getWidth(), fl_web_webview_activity.getHeight());
```

If you use `mWebView` instead of `fl_web_webview_activity` it is working fine in below `Android 5.0` but in `Android 5.0` or above it returning a BLACK or WHITE bitmap.

**This implementation is perfectly working on every device below `Android 5.0` as well as above `Android 5.0`.**

Hope this implementation will help someone.

Thank You,

Comment: Thx for an answer, but suggested code takes snapshot of only visible part of WebView. My code takes the snapshot of webview content ,which is out of screen bounds. The answer on link in comment, under my question, is better in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078157/webview-draw-not-properly-working-on-latest-android-system-webview-update/30084485

Comment: @Ufkoku But I tested in Android 4.4,4.4.4,5.0,4.0 in all its taking snapshot of whole webview,so can I know your Mobile OS details?