# Android Webview to PDF using PdfDocument

Tags: android, android-webview, android-pdf-api

When attempting to create a PDF using PdfDocument from a Webview, my content is always blank.  Trying a very simple example (writting a report writter) and yet the string does not show up in the PDF.  The PDF is getting create, however the text is not showing up.

```
 WebView webview;

 String summary = "<html><body><h1>A very simple line of <b>text</b> </h1></body></html>";
 webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, summary,
         "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
int pageNumber = 1;
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(webview.getWidth(),
                       webview.getHeight(), pageNumber).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
webview.draw(page.getCanvas());
document.finishPage(page);
```

I also attempted to place this inside a custom webview and process in  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url), but still no string shown in PDF.

The PDF is RED.

Comment: not understand you problem . you want to draw pdf page in webview ? or you want to open pdf page in webview ?

Comment: Neither;  I want to create a "report" in a webview and then "draw it" into the page of the PdfDocument and save it as a PDF that I can them email or view with an intent(which I have that view PDF working, I'm just not seeing the text I put into the webview).

Comment: You should check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223117/draw-webview-into-a-canvas-in-android-l

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.  In the mean time I switched 

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));`

and then did a draw on the textview